# Spring Cloud Config - Encrypt Password

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I saw that spring cloud config provides an `/encrypt` and `/decrypt` endpoints. How can I use the encrypt and decrypt endpoint via Advanced REST Client in order to view the encrypted or decrypted string?

Comment: Just send a request to corresponding endpoints. What exactly is a advanced rest client?

Comment: It is a google chrome plugin for sending rest messages. This is the endpoint I am using https://ctpconfigserver.app.cloud.company.net/encrypt. Should I use get or post and how can I pass the string that I want to encrypt?

Answer (score 4):

As [Spring Cloud Config documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_encryption_and_decryption) states:

> The server also exposes `/encrypt` and `/decrypt` endpoints (on the
>   assumption that these will be secured and only accessed by authorized
>   agents). If you are editing a remote config file you can use the
>   Config Server to encrypt values by **POSTing** to the `/encrypt`
>   endpoint.

For encryption, send a `POST` request to the `/encrypt` endpoint with the *Clear Text* as the request body:

```
$ curl localhost:8888/encrypt -d mysecret
682bc583f4641835fa2db009355293665d2647dade3375c0ee201de2a49f7bda
```

> The inverse operation is also available via `/decrypt` (provided the
>   server is configured with a symmetric key or a full key pair).

For decryption, send a `POST` request to the `/decrypt` endpoint with the *Cipher Text* as the request body:

```
$ curl localhost:8888/decrypt -d 682bc583f4641835fa2db00935529366...
mysecret
```

Comment: @Ali - Could you please guide here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52128302/unable-to-call-the-encrypt-endpoint-with-spring-cloud-boot-in-v2-0-x ?