# Unable to call the /encrypt endpoint with Spring Cloud + boot in v2.0.X

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I was using the Spring Cloud and Security example. In this example, I was using Spring Boot version `1.4.1.RELEASE`. Spring Boot parent version to `2.0.4.RELASE`. The moment I updated the dependency following endpoint started breaking.

I already went through [Spring Cloud Config - Encrypt Password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37488311/spring-cloud-config-encrypt-password) and documentation http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud.html, but not sure why I am getting forbiddeb error.

I tried using CURL and POSTMAN, get the forbidden error.

> C:\Users\pc>curl localhost:8888/encrypt -d connectionstring=server123;user=root;password@word1
>   {"timestamp":"2018-09-01T12:53:17.382+0000","status":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Forbidden","path":"/encrypt"}
>   C:\Users\pc>

*NOTE: My Server running on port 8888 fine & JCE files are added already*

POST : http://localhost:8888/encrypt

[image]

The code I used below

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

**application.yml**

```
---

server:
  port: 8888


spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/rseroter/pluralsight-spring-cloudconfig-wa-tolls

          search-paths:
          - 'station*'
          repos:
            perf: 
              pattern:
              - "*/perf"
              uri : https://github.com/rseroter/pluralsight-spring-cloudconfig-wa-tolls-perf
              search-paths :
              - 'station*'

# Enable security for Basic Auth
  security:
    user:
      name: ABC_123
      password: ABC##123
```

**bootstrap.properties**

```
encrypt.key=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
    }
}
```

Project structure:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that Spring Security enables csrf protection by default. You can read [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html) for more information.

Simply disable csrf protection will help /encrypt to be accessible again.

```
http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/encrypt/**")
            .permitAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

[thanh ngo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52159755/2181576) answer worked for me with some modifications.

First, if you're trying this on spring boot, mvcMatcher may not work. If you're just practicing you could simply use

```
http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll().and().csrf().disable();
```

The entire class would look something like

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll().and().csrf().disable();
    }
```